# Ошибка ReferenceError: b is not defined в reduce

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как правильно написать цикл `reduce` по склеиванию массива с условием?

Пытаюсь сделать без цикла `for`

```js
function buttons(opts, act) {
  return opts.reduce((a, b) => {
    if (b == act) return `<button class="active">${b}<button>`;
    else return `<button>${b}<button>`;
  }, b);
}

document.querySelector('.buttons').innerHTML(buttons([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3));
```

```html
<div class="buttons"></div>
```

Comment: Правильнее было бы обычный `forEach`

Comment: Хочу просто сделать без создания лишних переменных в памяти

Comment: то есть a и b  и то, что создаёт внутри себя reduce - это не лишняя память? ...понятно

Comment: а ты микропроцессоры пишешь, что 0.000001 памяти экономишь?

Comment: она в цикле будет крутиться по созданию много и разных кнопок, возможно по памяти преувеличил, гдето это читал что создание каждой переменно это какой то постоянный ресурс в памяти занимает, плохо в этом разбираюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function buttons(opts, act) {
    return opts.reduce((a, b) => {
        if (b == act) 
            a += `<button class="active">${b}</button>`;
        else 
            a += `<button>${b}</button>`;
    
        return a;
    }, '');
}

document.querySelector('.buttons').innerHTML = buttons([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3);
```

```html
<div class="buttons"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function buttons(opts, act) {
  return opts.reduce((a, b) => {
    if (b == act) 
      return a + `<button class="active">${b}</button>`;
    else 
      return a + `<button>${b}</button>`;
  }, "");
}

document.querySelector('.buttons').innerHTML = buttons([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons"></div>
```